# Area of triangle which hypotenuse=10

Tags: geometry

A right triangle has a hypotenuse equal to 10 and an altitude to the hypotenuse equal to 6. Find the area of the triangle.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the area of a triangle?

Comment: Of course. It's half times base times height.

Comment: Right...and here you know the base and the height.

Comment: This is a trick question,folks! (What's the maximum possible altitude if the hypotenuse is $6$?)

Comment: Isn't that a job-interview question asked in Microsoft just recently (with the altitude being equal to one of the sides, making this triangle impossible to exist)?

Comment: @TonyK  Good point.

Comment: This question was out in my class test. Got it wrong